# libvlc - Can't call function from callback

Tags: c++, c, gtk, vlc

I'm writing a GTK/VLC program. As in normal media player, my program should act as follows:

1. Double click on `playlist` (implemented using `GtkTreeView`) makes the `player` (implemented using `libvlc_media_player`) plays the selected media.
2. When media end is reached, the `player` raises an event. This event is used to call a routine that:

   - search for the next media in `playlist`
   - the `g_signal_emit` function is used to simulate the double click event in the playlist in order to select the next media.

The problem is that the function "play" of the `player` can't be called by the same thread of a callback of `player` itself.

How can I get out from this mess?

** Additions **
vlc signals seem to be asynchronous while gtk's do not. Is there a way to emit asynchronously gtk's events?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to start another thread (or send message to another thread) and run command there. It's well known problem with callbacks in libvlc.

That's how I did it:

```
void player::libvlc_event( const struct libvlc_event_t* event )
{
    //come from another thread
    if( libvlc_MediaPlayerEndReached == event->type ||
        libvlc_MediaPlayerEncounteredError == event->type )
    {
        if( mode_single != get_playback_mode() ) {
            //to avoid deadlock we should execute commands on another thread
            std::thread th( &player::next, this );
            th.detach();
        }
    }
}
```